# How do I write a function which returns the output of a unary expression on a dense Eigen object?

Tags: c++, eigen

As an example, suppose I want to write a function that checks whether each floating point number in a dense eigen object is `normal`, and returns `1.0` for the corresponding position if it is normal, or `0.0` if it is not. The output must not be evaluated immediately, and would preferably be in the form of an expression.

I've read through the [documentation on passing eigen objects as parameters](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html), which has led me to attempt the following:

```
#include <functional>                                                              

#include <Eigen/Dense>                                                             

template <typename Derived>                                                        
auto Fun(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& matrix) -> decltype(matrix.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun<typename Derived::Scalar, bool>(std::isnormal)).template cast<typename Derived::Scalar>())
{                                                                                  
    return matrix.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun<typename Derived::Scalar, bool>(std::isnormal)).template cast<typename Derived::Scalar>();
}                                                                                  

int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> mat;                                             
    mat.resize(100,100);                                                           
    mat.fill(100);                                                                 
    auto mat2 = Fun(mat);                                                          

    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

This fails with the error that `unaryExpr` is not defined for an object of type `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`, and sure enough, if I look at [the documentation for `DenseBase`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html) I see that there is no such function.

So then, short of forcing evaluation every time I want to call this function and casting the eigen object to an evaluated `Matrix`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: answered there: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=122553#p318192